# how can I execute a javascript program 30 after page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I execute a javascript program 30 after page loads, and I have to execute it repeatedly in 30 seconds. I would like to use jquery since I already included in my document

Thank you guys

Comment: Do you want to execute 30 seconds later, or once a second for 30 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute it 30 times, once a second, you'd use setInterval.

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
     // do stuff
}, 1000);

window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
}, 30 * 1000);
```

Comment: Interesting interpretation of "execute it repeatedly in 30 seconds". ;)

Comment: The question wasn't clear, so I made a best guess considering he wants to execute "30 after page loads". 30 times, or 30 seconds? He mentioned repeatedly, so here we are. Plus, someone answered the other interpretation already.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) method:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // This will execute 30s after the page loads 
    // and it will execute only once
}, 30000);
```

If you want to repeat the execution of the function on every 30 seconds you could use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) method.

As far as jquery is concerned you don't need to to use it for such a simple task as it is already built into javascript.

Comment: And to repeat it every 30 seconds, replace setTimeout with setInterval. :)

Comment: If one wants to be very precise, *jQuery* (itself) does not even offer a functionality for that ;)

Answer (score 3):

You want [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) here, like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  alert("It's been 30 seconds");
}, 30000);
```

[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) will fire after the delay (so 30 seconds in) then again every time the delay is up (every 30 seconds as desired).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
   setInterval(function() {
      $("#data1").load('1.php');
   }, 30000);
});
```

Just substitute your jQuery function in :)